# Condition for a stochastic matrix to be a second order transition probability matrix of a DTMC.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ stochastic matrix $$A=\left(
>  \begin{array}{cc}
>  1-a & a  \\
>   b &   1-b\\
>  \end{array}\right).
> $$
>   Then A is a second order transition probability matrix of a DTMC, i.e. there is a DTMC with probability matrix P such that $P^{2}=A$ iff $a+b\leq 1$.

**Attempt.** The desired property holds iff $$A=\left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
 1-a & a  \\
  b &   1-b\\
 \end{array}\right) = \left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
 1-p & p  \\
  q &   1-q\\
 \end{array}\right)^2
$$ for some $p,~q\in [0,1]$, that is $a=2p-pq-p^2,~b=2q-pq-q^2$ for some $p,~q\in [0,1]$. I am not sure how this leads to the equivalent desired condition $a+b\leq 1$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a = 2p - pq - p^2$ and $b = 2q - pq - q^2$, then we can add these together to get $$a+b = 2p+2q - 2pq - p^2 - q^2 = 2(p+q) - (p+q)^2 = (p+q)(2-p-q).$$
But $x(2-x)$ is at most $1$ for any $x$, so $a+b$ can be at most $1$. We could also be clever with our algebra and write $$a+b = 2p+2q - 2pq - p^2 - q^2 = 1 - (p+q-1)^2$$ from which you can see that $a+b$ can be at most $1$, and is only exactly $1$ when $p+q=1$.

---

That's half of the implication; the other half is trickier, because it requires you to solve these two equations for $p$ and $q$. However, notice that $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{2p-pq-p^2}{2q-pq-q^2} = \frac{p}{q}.$$ So we can take one of these equations and write it as $$a = 2p - p\left(\frac ba \cdot p\right) - p^2 \implies \left(1 + \frac ba\right)p^2 - 2p + a = 0$$
which is a quadratic equation with solutions $$p = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4a - 4b}}{2 + \frac{2b}{a}} \implies p = \frac{a}{a+b}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{1-a-b}\right).$$
So we can always solve for $p$ and get a real number if $a+b \le 1$.

Comment: Great. +1  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your equations imply
\begin{align*}
a + b = (1-p)(p+q) + (1-q)(p+q),
\end{align*}
maximising the function
$$
F(p,q) = (1-p)(p+q) + (1-q)(p+q)
$$
over the unit square, formally using Lagrangian multipliers or by heuristically guessing straight from symmetry this is maximised on the set $ p + q = 1$ and so
$$
a + b = F(p,q) \leq 1.
$$
 **Edit**  I have run out of time a little and I hope to come back to this but this is what I have so far for showing the equivalence in the other direction, it needs more work and also handling of the degenerate cases where $a$ or $b$ is equal to zero, I have posted it in the hope it will still help.

Let 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 - a & a \\
b & 1-b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then we can we find the eigenvalue, eigenvector pairs
$$
\lambda_1 = 1,\; \; v_1 = 1
$$
and
$$
\lambda_2 = 1 - (a+b), \; \; v_2 = (-\frac{a}{b}, 1)
$$
so we can use the usual spectral decomposition to write $A$ as
$$
A = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{V}^{-1}
$$
now assuming $a+b \leq 1$ we have
\begin{align}
P &=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\frac{a}{b} \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{1 - (a+b)}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\frac{a}{b} \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\frac{a}{b} \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{1 - (a+b)}
\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a+b}
\begin{pmatrix}
b & a \\
-b & b 
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}
Working all this through gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a}{a+b}\sqrt{1-(a+b)} + \frac{b}{a+b} & 
\frac{a}{a+b} - \frac{a}{a+b}\sqrt{1-(a+b)}\\
\frac{b}{a+b} - \frac{b}{a+b}\sqrt{1-(a+b)} & \frac{b}{a+b}\sqrt{1-(a+b)} + \frac{a}{a+b}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which after a bit of checking a tidying should be equivalent to a matrix of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p & 1 - p \\
1 - q & q
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Great. This means that if such $p,~q$ exist, then $a+b\leq 1$ (which makes $a+b\leq 1$ a necessary condition). Why is it enough also?

Comment: Ok sure give me a second I will edit my answer